# Xamarin.Forms propagating TapGestureRecognizer event to parent

Tags: xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer

Recently I have with issue of how to propagate `TapGestureRecognizer` events to parent view ?!

Consider the following example:

```xml
<ParentView>
    <ChildView>
    <!-- Here is used TapGestureRecognizer, but touch event do not raised to ParentView -->
    </ChildView>
</ParentView>
```

Here is part of my custom view that in above example is called `ChildView`:

```cs
    public class ChildView : Frame
    {
        public ChildView()
        {
            Clicked += TryExecuteCommand;
            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
            {
                // Some logic
                Clicked?.Invoke(s, e);
            };
            GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        }
        ...
    }
```

I know that in `WPF` was Handled property on `*EventArgs` ... is there the similar solution for `Xamarin.Forms` ?

Comment: Hi ,could you share a detail scene to explain that ? This will be helpful to understand how to achieve that .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I mean I what to add TapGestureRecognizer to ParentView and receive Tap event also ... but I cannot because ChildView do not send it up (

Comment: Okey , if native platform can achieve that , xamarin forms also can . You can use Custom  Renderer to have a try with each needed platform . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers#layouts